# Debug assertion failed in OPENCV3 detectAndCompute

Tags: c++, opencv

I am compiling one of the DBoW3 demos (demo_general) in debug profile with VS2015.

The demo creates a bag of words based on a selected feature (orb, surf, akaze, brisk, etc) and some images.

The first stage is to detect and extract features from the images:

```
fdetector=cv::ORB::create();
fdetector->detectAndCompute(image, cv::Mat(), keypoints, descriptors);
```

The last line throws an exception when reaching a copy operation within the OpenCV3 implementation of ORB.cpp (line 891):

```
std::copy(allKeypoints.begin() + offset, allKeypoints.begin() + offset + nkeypoints, keypoints.begin());
```

An screenshot of the exception:

[image: Debug assertion Failed]

Using other feature descriptors leads to the same error at similar operations, this is, the use of an iterator as: `allKeypoints.begin() + offset`

Note again that this is an unmodified OpenCV function. I also verified that in the first iteration `offset` is zero while `nkeypoints` is small such that the vector bounds are not exceeded.

Although in most cases this error comes from violating the vector boundaries, I actually believe it has more to do with different signatures of the libraries used for debugging as pointed in:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/99a01298-865d-4451-b8c6-3e25db5cbcee/vector-iterator-offset-out-of-range?forum=vclanguage.
However, that post does not offer a conclusive fix.

What other information could be useful to narrow more on the error?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of step-wise debugging seems that one has to set the macro _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL equal to 1.
This can be done in VS2015 under Project Properties>C/C++>Preprocessor>Preprocessor Definitions.
I got a new debug assertion error though. I will keep fighting and enhance my answer later.